# Link Error in class template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

Please have a look at the following code

**Calculator.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template<class T>


class Calculator
{
public:
    Calculator(void);
    ~Calculator(void);

    void add(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x+y) << endl;
    }

    void min(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x-y) << endl;
    }

    void max(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x*y) << endl;
    }

    void dev(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x/y) << endl;
    }
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Calculator.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Calculator<double> c;
    c.add(23.34,21.56);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the below error. I am not much familiar with class templates. Please help!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TemplateCalculator, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\yohan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TemplateCalculator\Debug\TemplateCalculator.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: main() in Calculator.h ???

Comment: Probably because you've got your `main` function in a header file. Move it into `Calculator.cpp`, `#include Calculator.h` in it, and then try compiling.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: They can be igonred. This is the complete code. numbers[2] is an array I just created for the future use. I will not need it anyway

Comment: @billz: I did it in that way because my power point slide which contains the tutorial has done it in that way

Comment: try to rename Calculator.h to Calculator.cpp?

Comment: @billz: I edited the code. Please have a look

Comment: code should compile if you provide definition for constructor and destructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threw this into VS2010 really quick. It was not liking cout and endl due to not using namespace std. I just put in a using statement for speed. I prefer to use std:: conventions normally because this avoids naming issues that 'using' can generate

Also It complained about no constructor and destructor (added in {}'s)

And like a previous comment said, having your main in a header file is probably bad too. This is all in a default project in test.cpp

**EDIT** I changed the file structure to have the Calculator in a .h

Calculator.h

```
template<class T>


class Calculator
{
public:
    Calculator(void)
    {
    }
    ~Calculator(void)
    {
    }

    void add(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x+y) << endl;
    }

    void min(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x-y) << endl;
    }

    void max(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x*y) << endl;
    }

    void dev(T x, T y)
    {
        cout << (x/y) << endl;
    }

private:
    T numbers[2];
};
```

Test.cpp

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"


#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Calculator.h"

int main()
{

    Calculator<double> c;
    c.add(23.34,21.56);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add definition for constructor and destructor

```
 Calculator(void)  {}
 ~Calculator(void) {}
```

In `Calculator.h` you need to tell compiler `cout` and `endl` are from `std` namespace. For example:

```
std::cout << (x*y) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project type is probably wrong.
You need to write this code in a console application.

By the way, the other answers also need to be considered especially defining of the constructor and destructor.